# Getting "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!" in sample application

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, botframework

I've cloned the official [BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) repository and I'm running the sample named AadV2Bot ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV2Bot))

It's the **"Bot example that uses an OAuthCard to log a user into an AAD v2 application and uses the Microsoft Graph Api"**

Well, I haven't modified anything but `web.config`.

However, I cannot get it working.
Inside the Bot Emulator, all I'm getting is this after I send a message ("Hola")

[image]

I think I've put the correct my information in `web.config`:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you set those AppId / AppPassword on the emulator also?

Comment: I didn't know that I had to set it, since the bot isn't published in Azure! How is that?

Comment: If you put the app ID and password in your bot, the emulator will try to validate against those credentials.  So either both or neither have to have the credentials, they have to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please cross check your `filename.bot` file with below code.

```
{
    "name": "final",
    "description": "",
    "secretKey": "",
    "services": [
        {
            "appId": "",
            "id": "xxxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxxxx",
            "type": "endpoint",
            "appPassword": "",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
            "name": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages"
        }
    ]
}
```

(make sure you mention `http` for `endpoint` and `name`)

Comment: Please, could you explain why is that necessary, if the bot is running on my local system? I thought that data was only necessary when it's running on Azure. I'm so confused!