# Slack messages don't reach botframework GA

Tags: botframework, slack-api

I followed the [MS documentation on how to configure a Slack channnel for a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). But I believe it is outdated because it talks about dev.botframework.com configuration and not from the Azure portal.
Interestingly enough the URL slack.botframework.com for configuring the api still works. 
But the issue is that even debugging my bot locally with ngrok, the only message that reaches the bot is one when I try to authorize the channel in slack, after that when I write a message it doesn't reach the bot.

Comment: Hi Martin! I have one request and one question. Can you link the tutorial you used to configure (the outdated one) and the question is: does that tutorial instruct you to change the messaging endpoint on Azure? (Currently (8-9-18) Azure is experiencing a bug where altering the messaging endpoint causes the bot to cease responding. The team is working on the issue, but if this is not the case, we can look deeper into your issue.

Comment: No it doesn’t instruct to do that. I did change the messaging endpoint for being able to redirect the messages to my local debugging instance using ngrok though. But I did that because just following the instructions didn’t work. I’ll update the question with the tutorial

Comment: If there is error with ngrok, follw this steps
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558069/getting-botauthenticator-failed-to-authenticate-incoming-request-in-sample-ap/51563495#51563495

Comment: I don't think there's an error with ngrok

Comment: It's not an ngrok error, it's a documentation error. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doc is outdated, to some extent. The portion **UP TO** connecting your Slack App to Bot Framework is correct, however, there are both difference and addtional steps that must be taken from that point.

As you're aware, the bot must be created in the Azure Portal. **AFTER** the step that instructs you to create a Bot User on the Slack API page, go ahead and swap over to Azure and create your bot. For assistance on how to do that, you can follow [Create A Bot with Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Once your bot is created and deployed successfully, click over to the Bot Management Setting  blade. You're going to need your bot handle, and ***YES it is case sensitive***. That is what you're going to use for your 'Subscribe to Bot Events' Request URL.

[image: Settings and Bot Handle]

From there, you can go ahead and follow the **'Subscribe to Bot Events'**, **'Add and Configure Interactive Messages (optional)'**, and **'Gather credentials'** sections of the tutorial as is.

Next, head back to Azure Portal and your bot there. Click the **Channels** under Bot Management (link above settings), scroll to the bottom, and select **Slack**. THAT is where you're going to put your Slack credentials. Once you push save, a new window will open, asking you to Authorize your bot. Go ahead and click 'Authorize'.

[image: Authorize Bot]

The Tutorial ends there, however, there are a few small steps that still need to be taken. Go back to the Slack App and click **'Basic Information'**. On the main screen, there is a list of checked steps under the heading **'Building Apps for Slack'** Click on the one that says **'Install your app to your workspace'** (1), then click the button that says 'Install App to Workspace'(2)

[image: Install App to Workspace and Authorize]

Once more, a new window will pop up, asking for authorization. Again, select 'Authorize'

[image: Authorize Final]

After that, wait a few minutes for Slack to finalize the authorization on their end (I've had a bot take 5 min to authorize the connection). Then, you can go back into the Slack workspace, and either directly message your bot or add them to a channel and test.

Comment: Ok, I can't believe this. I have been doing what you said and it didn't work. Actually I was doing those steps except for respecting the casing of the bot handle!!! That was it!
Slack verifies the URL just fine, but then the messages don't reach the bot.
Thank you so much! I've lost so many days because of this silly thing. Shame on me.