# Connecting an Azure Bot to Slack - error 'No message text provided'

Tags: botframework, slack, slack-api, azure-bot-service

I am working on a Q&A bot in Azure and connecting it to Slack. I choose the no-code path with just configuration in Azure and Slack.

I was  successful in the following:

- Creating the Q&A service in Azure
- Importing my FAQ
- Creating a BOT in azure and testing it in the 'Test in Web chat 'pane
- Creating an app in Slack and sending it text. However I never get a reply from my FAQ text.

So the error are:

- In Slack, the response is always 'No good match in FAQ.' Im assuming this is the default text for the Bot.
- In Azure, the Channels tab showed the Health of the Slack channel as red with issues. The text reads 'No message text provided' for every call made. This implies Slack is not sending the text to the bot.

Has anyone else seen this error  'No message text provided' when connecting to Slack?

Next things to try are:

- Try and download the code and bot emulator and debug the error following these steps 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Any help / thoughts would be appreciated.

Vince

Comment: Hi Vince! Two questions: 1) does your bot respond with the proper QnA answer when using 'Test in Web Chat'? and 2) is is possible your slack connection is misconfigured? The old 'Connect your bot to slack' tutorial is a bit...incorrect, but there's an update how to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749445/slack-messages-dont-reach-botframework-ga/51773708#51773708

Comment: Yes it works correcly in the 'Test in Web Chat'. Thanks for the link. Ill let you know.

Comment: I followed the article and it still does not work. 

A few differences I note from the article I followed 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

- I did not name the bot use testapp (I dont think this should matter) 
- Re event subscription I subscribed to bot events not worksapce events, since this sent interaction to all Slack channels in the workspace.

I think that is all. I will have to debug now - I am expecting the messages will still not arrive from Slack so I dont think its going to help me fix this.

Comment: Note that I am running this from within a internal company network so I wonder if it is firewall related. What is another easy channel to setup? I tried:

1) Skype - dont want to use - needs approval and the bot goes to a public bot directory
2) Cortnana - my Office 365 Business account does not have Cortana enabled so this did not work, and I was not able to sign into Cortana with my Office 365 Home account.

Thanks

Comment: Good news. After a republish on QnA maker and following them steps it now works. Thanks for your help.